# How to select NULL value, as a string, sort of

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate SQL statements from contents in a db, basically to migrate data from one db to another by generating INSERT statements. But I'm not having any luck with NULL values

Example table t1:

```
    c1   c2
r1 'a'   NULL
r2 'b'   'c'
```

```sql
select 'INSERT INTO t2 (c1, c2) VALUES (''' + c1 + ''', ''' + c2 + ''')' from t1
```

I would like the output:

```sql
INSERT INTO t2 (c1, c2) VALUES ('a', NULL)
INSERT INTO t2 (c1, c2) VALUES ('b', 'c')
```

but the first just gives me NULL as output. I've tried various versions of `ISNULL()` and other such to get what I'm after, but come up with no working solution.
Right now I'm using `ISNULL(c2, 'REPLACEWITHNULL')` and doing a search&replace after the statements are generated, but I'd like to remove that second step, if possible.

### -------------- Solution below! --------------

Once I got the solution from DouadyRabbit I came up with another solution, not using CASE statement, which is a bit more compact:

```
+  IIF(c1 IS NULL, 'NULL', '''' + c1 + '''') +
```

Thanks a million DouadyRabbit!

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? Why do you want to create these statements?This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: `+ ISNULL('''' + c1 + '''', 'NULL') +`

Comment: If you want to migrate data use `INSERT ... SELECT` statements, don't generate `INSERT`s by string concatenation. It's a *lot* easier and faster. You can also script the entire database, including the data, from a client tool like SSMS or Azure Data Studio. String concatenation will cause problems with numbers and dates, not just NULLs. Never mind

Comment: Honestly, there are plenty of tools to help with migration. Be that by the generation of scripts, backup and restore processes, or self enclosed ETL processes. It is far from often that you need to completely build one yourself like this. Not to mention that making the poor target database `INSERT` every row 1 agonising row at a time will be *awful* for perforamance.

Comment: The reason for doing it this way is that it's application configuration data in the db (IBM Maximo), with id's that are different in every environment and references between objects, and I need to pick certain data from the dev environment to import to other environments.
It's not a lot of data, maybe 10-30 rows each time, but believe me, they are a pain to do...
I'm doing this as a stored procedure so I can just pinpoint the data I want and have the procedure produce the insert statements I need.

Comment: If you must do this, rather than replace() consider  ... + coalesce(c2,'REPLACEWITHNULL') + ...

Answer (score 0):

There are better methods to migrate a database, but you must have a valid reason to do it this way. The code below should help you.

```
DECLARE @sourceTable TABLE (c1 VARCHAR(10) NULL, c2 VARCHAR(10) NULL)

INSERT INTO @sourceTable (c1, c2) VALUES ('a', NULL), ('b',   'c'), (NULL, 'd')

--SELECT * FROM  @sourceTable

SELECT 'INSERT INTO t2 (c1, c2) VALUES (' + CASE 
                                                WHEN c1 IS NULL THEN 'NULL' 
                                                ELSE  '''' + c1 + ''''
                                            END + ', ' +
                                            CASE 
                                                    WHEN c2 IS NULL THEN 'NULL' 
                                                    ELSE  ''''+ c2 + ''''
                                            END + ') '
FROM @sourceTable
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work! And believe me, there are reasons for doing it this way (IBM is using the same approach, the end result anyway). And putting it in a procedure makes seconds out of hours of manual work!